# Is there a way to have a message box appear with a button to open an email template?

Tags: excel

Good Afternoon,

I have the below code which triggers when a cell in the referenced range pops up telling the person what they should do. What i now need to do is firstly make this pop up only appear when a date is explicitly entered into the referenced range, secondly i also need this pop up box to have a button that then opens a new email message that automatically populates the To, CC, Subject and Body elements.

Heres the code i have thus far,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I7:I51")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "You have entered a date in Attempt 3, you must now send an email to request a text message chaser, click the open email button below"  & Target, vbOKOnly, "Warning"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using Outlook or Thunderbird as a mail provider?

Comment: Im using outlook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether the `Target` is a date or not, you just need the `IsDate` function:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I7:I51")) Is Nothing Then
        If IsDate(Target) Then
            MsgBox "You have entered a date in Attempt 3, you must now send an email to request a text message chaser, click the open email button below" & Target, vbOKOnly, "Warning"
            Send_Emails
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub Send_Emails()
'This code is early binding i.e in Tools > Reference >You have check "MICROSOFT OUTLOOK 14.0 OBJECT LIBRARY"

    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With OutlookMail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .Display
        .HTMLBody = "Dear ABC" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Please find the attached file" & .HTMLBody
        'last .HTMLBody includes signature from the outlook.
                                                   '<br> includes line breaks b/w two lines
        .To = "abc@gmail.com"
        .CC = "sdf@gamil.com"
        .BCC = "hello@gamil.com;hi@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "Test mail"
        .Attachments = ThisWorkbook
        .Send
    End With

End Sub
```

Regarding the `Send_Emails` Sub, I didn't have the occasion to test it (since I don't have outlook), but you can tweak the parameters to get what you want. You could also include `To`, `CC` and all the fields as parameters to pass from the main `Worksheet_change` sub. Tell me if you need a hand in that regard.

Comment: Hi, this is returning a compile error User defined type not defined and then shows this in yellow Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application

Comment: Have you checked  "MICROSOFT OUTLOOK 14.0 OBJECT LIBRARY" under Tools > Reference?

Comment: Apologies, i checked and it wasn't turned on. Thanks,

Comment: Is there a way to change the fonts used by Outlook, the fonts start with one type and then use another type, id prefer to keep it to one specific font if possible?

Comment: Try this in the HTML body? `"<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Hello, World!</BODY>"`

Comment: Francesco, you have been amazing, it works superbly and has really made a massive difference in the way the document will work. truly grateful.

Comment: I'm glad you found your solution!